# How to style the active element in VS Code's activity bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Per the [October release of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40), the border and background of the Activity Bar's active element can now be controlled via `activityBar.activeBorder` and `activityBar.activeBackground`.

But adding these to my `settings.json` doesn't seem to update the active element:

```
"other.setting.foo": "bar",
"activityBar.activeBorder": "#8A2BE2",
"activityBar.activeBackground": "#FFB6C1"
"other.setting.baz": "qux",
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`activityBar.activeBorder` and `activityBar.activeBackground` need to be nested inside `workbench.colorCustomizations`:

```
"other.setting.foo": "bar",
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.activeBorder": "#8A2BE2",
    "activityBar.activeBackground": "#FFB6C1"
},
"other.setting.baz": "qux",
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84316#issuecomment-552014640